# Help understanding JQuery Attribute Equals Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find a `<td role="foo" class="one two three four">` within a `<div id="myid">`

These two selectors work:

```
$('#myid td[role=foo]')

$('#myid .two')
```

But this one doesn't, why?

```
$('#myid .two td[role=foo]')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because a space in a selector string [is a descendant-selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

You would need to do:

```
$('#myid td.two[role=foo]')
```

The way you had it, you were searching for `<td role="foo">` elements that are a *descendant* of `.two`.

Comment: @Nick - Is that way more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Because your selector:

```
$('#myid .two td[role=foo]')
```

is looking for a `td[role=foo]` *within* an element of class `.two` *within* an element of id `#myid`.

You're using descendant selectors, rather than looking for `td[role=foo].two` which, I think, is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
$("#myid td[role=foo].two")...
```

This selector:

```
$('#myid .two td[role=foo]')
```

means: find the element with ID "myid". From it find all descendants with a class of "two". From those elements find all descendants `<td>` elements that have a role attribute with a value of "foo".