# Which CSS Selector style is more efficient?

Tags: jquery-selectors, performance

Inspired by [Help understanding JQuery Attribute Equals Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814966/help-understanding-jquery-attribute-equals-selector) the question is:

Which of these is more efficient?

```
$('#FOO element.BAR[attr=BAZ]')
```

or

```
$('#FOO element[attr=BAZ].BAR')
```

And yes, we could omit the initial #FOO selector, but that question was asking about that in particular, so ... sobeit

Also, while my syntax above uses jQuery, that's just because it was convenient for me to leave it so. <strike>The same syntax would be found in a CSS document, no?</strike> apparently that isn't the same, let's limit it to jQuery then?

Comment: "The same syntax would be found in a CSS document, no?"  Yes, but it's generally a completely different implementation (exception being if [querySelectorAll](http://ejohn.org/blog/queryselectorall-in-firefox-31/) is used), so you should probably limit your question to jQuery.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen ~ Can you expound upon that? Completely different implementation, do you mean to the DOM parser?

Comment: both the CSS parser and the code to determine which DOM elements match which selectors are different.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen ... hence my curiousity and the question ;)

Comment: you're asking which is more efficient, but my point is that this is really (at least) two different questions.  It may be that #1 is more efficient for jQuery's selector engine but #2 is more efficient when interpreted directly by the browser as CSS.  Or vice versa.  Of course, it depends on which browser too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly [quick and dirty demo](http://jsbin.com/ozace3) shows a 1-5ms discrepancy between the two approaches, and is inconsistent between which is the faster. I imagine that the test could be much improved though.

Anyway, over ten page-loads (all times are in milliseconds):

```
page load     |       $('#foo td.one[title=baz]')     |        $('#foo td[title=baz].one')
--------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
1             |                 9                     |                    8
2             |                 7                     |                    6
3             |                 8                     |                    8
4             |                 8                     |                    8
5             |                 8                     |                    7
6             |                 8                     |                    8
7             |                 7                     |                   11
8             |                 8                     |                    7
9             |                 7                     |                    7
10            |                 8                     |                    8
--------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
total         |                78                     |                   78
```

So...insofar as I can conclude *anything* from that, it appears that `$('#foo td.one[title=baz]')` is *marginally* faster, but, on average they come out about the same.

Comment: It would help if the version of jQuery you are benchmarking is made explicit, since different versions have had different optimisations for selectors.